# Get rid of MongoDB extensions to JSON format

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

When converting BSON to JSON, [MongoDB adds the extensions to the JSON format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json).

However, these extensions bother our front-end design a lot.

Could someone suggest any Java API which can get rid of these extensions added by MongoDB?

For example, here is what MongoDB gives us :

```
{"createdDate" : { "$date" : "2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"}}
```

But what we want is :

```
{"createdDate" : "2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"}
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to import the JSON into the appropriate domain object in Java, then format the result however you want.  In the example you gave, you could import a POJO that has a `Date createdDate` property, then use a `SimpleDateFormatter` to format the result however you want.  Another option would be to write a custom deserializer that will bubble up the `$date` value to the parent.

More info on writing custom serializers and deserializers here: http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html